# How to clear cookies in WebKit?

Tags: python, cookies, webkit

i'm currently working with PyWebKitGtk in python (http://live.gnome.org/PyWebKitGtk). I would like to clear all cookies in my own little browser. I found interesting method webkit.HTTPResponse.clearCookies() but I have no idea how to lay my hands on instance of HTTPResponse object :/

I wouldn't like to use java script for that task.

Comment: Which Python WebKit API are you using?

Comment: Hmmm -- do you mean the part of good old webware that is (or used to be) known as webkit, server-side; or, the very popular browser-building/rendering toolkit that underlies e.g. Safari and Chrome and is variously interfaced to Python (client-side) via Qt, Gtk, wx, ...?  It makes a huge difference, of course (e.g., if server-side, why are you keeping cookies in the first place and how? no surprise that cookies are only in Http requests and responses from a server's viewpoint...!), including, if client-side, what GUI toolkit are you using with it -- so please clarify!

Comment: Question is about PyWebKitGtk (http://live.gnome.org/PyWebKitGtk), sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the current state of the bindings on [GitHub](https://github.com/jmalonzo/pywebkitgtk/), you'll see PyWebKitGTK [doesn't yet provide](https://github.com/jmalonzo/pywebkitgtk/blob/master/webkit/webkit-1.1-types.defs) quite what you want- there's not mapping for the `HTTPResponse` type it looks like. Unfortunately, I think Javascript or a proxy are your only options right now.

EDIT:

...unless, of course, you want it *real* bad and stay up into the night learning ctypes. In which case, you can do magic. To clear *all* the browser's cookies, try this.

```
import gtk, webkit, ctypes

libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('libwebkit-1.0.so')
libgobject = ctypes.CDLL('libgobject-2.0.so')
libsoup = ctypes.CDLL('libsoup-2.4.so')

v = webkit.WebView()

#do whatever it is you do with WebView...
....

#get the cookiejar from the default session
#(assumes one session and one cookiesjar)
generic_cookiejar_type = libgobject.g_type_from_name('SoupCookieJar')
cookiejar = libsoup.soup_session_get_feature(session, generic_cookiejar_type)

#build a callback to delete cookies
DEL_COOKIE_FUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_void_p)
def del_cookie(cookie):
    libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_delete_cookie(cookiejar, cookie)

#run the callback on all the cookies
cookie_list =  libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_all_cookies(cookiejar)
libsoup.g_slist_foreach(cookie_list, DEL_COOKIE_FUNC(del_cookie), None)
```

EDIT:

Just started needing this myself, and while it's the right idea it needed work. Instead, try this- the function type and cookiejar access are fixed.

```
#add a new cookie jar
cookiejar = libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_new()

#uncomment the below line for a persistent jar instead
#cookiejar = libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_text_new('/path/to/your/cookies.txt',False)

libsoup.soup_session_add_feature(session, cookiejar)

#build a callback to delete cookies
DEL_COOKIE_FUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p)
def del_cookie(cookie, userdata):
    libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_delete_cookie(cookiejar, cookie)
    return 0

#run the callback on all the cookies
cookie_list =  libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_all_cookies(cookiejar)
libsoup.g_slist_foreach(cookie_list, DEL_COOKIE_FUNC(del_cookie), None)
```

Note that you should only do this *before* using the WebView, or maybe in WebKit callbacks, or you will have threading issues above and beyond those usually associated with GTK programming.

Comment: Though now that I've done all that, I'm concerned you meant *only* for a specific request/response, which would be totally different =/